# Laravel cron job on cpanel is not running

Tags: laravel, cron, scheduled-tasks, cpanel

I'm trying to run a cron job for task scheduler in laravel 8 on cpanel

here is the command im entering in cpanel cron jobs page

`usr/local/bin/php /home/webservername/public_html/laravelappfolder/artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1`

the cron job is set to run once every minute

and in the Kernel.php looks like this(the schedule function part):

```
protected function schedule(Schedule $schedule)
    {   
        $schedule->call(function () {
            $d = DB::table('users')->where('userid', '=', 5)->first();
            $newAge = $d->age + 1;
            $d->update(['age'=> $newAge]);
        })->everyMinute();
    }
```

I'm doing a basic call to a function every minute, but nothing in the database is changing. I checked disable_functions thing but that line doesn't exist in my php.ini. I also tried doing Log::info('test') but no new logs to be found.

I also tried creating a command and calling it with its signature name and registering it in the $commands array, but same thing cron job not working

Comment: Could you show your Commands ?